# Facing issue while retrieving the document from MongoDB based on Date field

Tags: java, mongodb

Actually my date field in mongodb looks like this `"Date" : ISODate("2015-03-01T00:00:00.000+0000")`.

Based on this field I'm trying to retrieve the document using `java`.

But, I'm getting null while retrieving the document.

Regarding `conversion of String to Java Date Object` I'm facing issue.

Can anyone please help me out?

```
MongoDatabase db = mongoclient.getDatabase("myDB");
MongoCollection<Document> col = db.getCollection("myCol");

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+SSSS") ;
String oldDate = "2015-03-01T00:00:00.000+0000";
Date date = format.parse(oldDate);

Document doc = new Document();
doc.put("Date" , date);
System.out.println(col.find(doc).first());
```

Comment: I had resolved my issue by using the following code. DateTimeFormatter parser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
DateTime result = parser.parseDateTime("2015-03-01T05:30:00.000+0000");
Document doc = new Document();
doc.put("Date" , result.toDate());
col.insertOne(doc);

Comment: Hi dev777 - I think you've already asked this exact question already, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035791/facing-issue-while-inserting-the-document-from-mongodb-based-on-date-field. If you have more information to clarify the problem, you should edit your existing question - not post a new one.

Comment: If your solution is the fix for both questions, please post it against your other one, so that this question can be put on hold. Thanks.