# Facing issue while inserting the document from MongoDB based on Date field

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime

I want to insert one simple document having Date field like this:

```js
"Date" : ISODate("2015-03-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
```

But it is getting inserted as  another date `ISODate("2015-02-28T18:30:00.000+0000")`.

Here is my code:

```java
MongoDatabase db = mongoclient.getDatabase("myDB");
MongoCollection<Document> col = db.getCollection("myCol");

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+SSSS") ;
String oldDate = "2015-03-01T00:00:00.000+0000";
Date date = format.parse(oldDate);

Document doc = new Document();
doc.put("Date" , date);
col.insertone(doc)
System.out.println(col.find(doc).first());
```

Comment: It's not clear what you expect `SSS+SSSS` to mean in `SimpleDateFormat`. Do you understand that `+0000` is meant to be a UTC offset? (I very strongly suspect you can remove MongoDb from the equation here, and demonstrate the problem *just* with `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`.)

Comment: Yeah I'm also thinking that while conversion only, I'm facing problem. Can you please edit the code over here.

Comment: Um, no - *you* need to edit the question to clarify it and ideally remove the MongoDb aspect. Try to provide a [mcve], at which point we're more likely to be able to help you. Read the SimpleDateFormat documentation carefully though... you may well find that's all you need.